# A stupid puzzle, but a reward of pizza

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The other day I was presented with the following problem:

> If half of $5$ is $3$, then what is a third of $10$?

I figured that starting with a false assumption would mean that the "correct" answer to the problem would not be found through normal math conventions. There would probably be some clever answer where you draw a horizontal line through the $5$ (cutting it in half) and then reflect the bottom half up over that line which would create a $3$, hence getting "half of $5$ is $3$". Then doing something similar for a third of $10$ would get you the answer to the problem. I'm a kind of cheeky person so I just scratched out on paper $$\frac{5}{2} = 3  \implies 10 = 12  \implies \frac{10}{3} = 4$$ and ignored any attempt at a clever solution. However, then the person who presented me the riddle told me I had the right answer! I proceeded to point out to the person that starting with a false assumption could get you essentially any answer. For example, if $5 = 6$ then $6 = 5+1 = 6+1$ and $5 = 7 \implies \frac{10}{3} = \frac{14}{3} \neq 4$. You could continue this process and force $5$ to infinity. At this point I got challenged to prove that $\frac{10}{3}$ is equal to some quantity involving $\pi$ and $e$. My reward is a pizza. I immediately wrote $$\frac{10}{3} = \frac{10e\pi}{3e\pi} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{10}{3} = -\frac{10e^{i\pi}}{3}$$ but got shot down and the "nontrivial" condition was added to getting a solution. Here is where I come to MSE for help. I'm looking for a clever way to begin with the false assumption $\frac{5}{2} = 3$, and then by *using only* valid algebra/calculus deduce that $\frac{10}{3}$ is equal to *some* quantity involving $\pi$ and $e$ in a nontrivial way. I was considering writing $\pi = 3\cdot 10^0+1\cdot 10^{-1}+4\cdot 10^{-2} + \ldots$ so I could take advantage of the $10$'s that explicitly appear. Then I considered taking a look at the Taylor Series expansion of $e^\pi$. I haven't had any luck yet. If anyone has an idea on how to get a result like this, please feel free to offer suggestions!

Comment: We solve it and you get the pizza? Nice try! But $\pi + e^{-\sqrt{e}}$ is close.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll send you a piece pizza ;) Anyway, that quantity you provided would make for a very handsome solution. I'll see if I can force that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, start by multiplying by 2 and substracting 5 to your equality to get :

$$\frac{5}{2} = 3 \Leftrightarrow 0=1$$

Then it follow that

$$\frac{10}{3} = \frac{10 \times 1}{3} = \frac{10 \times 0}{3} = 0$$

But

$$e\pi = 1\times e\pi = 0\times e \pi = 0$$

And voila, we've proved that

$$\frac{10}{3} =e\pi$$

Obviously, you can show this way the equality between any two numbers

Comment: I'm getting a pizza! Much appreciated.

Comment: @graydad Now that you've proven that $e\pi$ is rational, feel free to also claim your Nobel prize.

Comment: @Farnight I'd prefer a Fields Medal but I suppose I'd settle for a Nobel Prize ;)

Comment: @graydad: There are no Nobel Prizes for mathematics. But for crackpot theories there is the Ig Nobel Prize...

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{10}{3}= 10\cdot \frac{2}{5}=4 =\left\lceil\frac{e^\pi-\pi}{5}\right\rceil.$$

Perhaps not what you were looking for, but if your challenger is good enough... Uh, you already won, lal. Well, I'll leave this here.